# Check if values in mysql database exist in multi dimensional array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have multiple ID's in an mysql database. I would like to know if there are ID's in the database which are not present in an multi dimensional array. For each ID which is not present in the multi dimensional array the row needs te be deleted. The following code is what I have so far.

```
function multi_array_search($search_for, $search_in) {
    foreach ($search_in as $element) {
        if ( ($element === $search_for) ) {
            return true;
        } elseif (is_array($element)) {
            $result = multi_array_search($search_for, $element);
            if($result == true)
                return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

$output = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM ads");
while ($g = mysql_fetch_array($output)) {
    echo multi_array_search("$g", $arr) ? 'Found' : 'Not found';
}
```

I don't think the above code is correct for what I want?

Information:
The $arr looks like:

```
Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( 
        [url] => http://
        [id] => 752 
    ) 
    [1] => Array ( 
        [url] => http://
        [id] => 758 
    )
)
```

I tryed some solutions now and none of the mare working :(

Comment: And why you think it is incorrect? Any errors?

Comment: Can't test it right now, I am not sure if the $g is a single ID from the database or a list of ID's?

Comment: Posting a question without even testing it once. -1

Answer (score 0):

Every thing seems to be fine. Just few updates to remove unwanted code from `elseif` and add one more check `!empty` into `elseif` condition.

```
function multi_array_search($search_for, $search_in) {
    foreach ($search_in as $element) {
        if ($element === $search_for){
            return true;
        }elseif(is_array($element) && !empty($element)){
            $result = multi_array_search($search_for, $element);
        }
    }
    return false;
}
$output = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM ads");
while ($g = mysql_fetch_array($output)) {
    echo multi_array_search("$g", $arr) ? 'Found' : 'Not found';
}
```

Hope will help!

Answer (score 0):

```
$removeid=array();
$idarray is the  multi dimensional array you want to check your database id with.
$result = 'store your databse id here in the form of an array';
foreach ($result as $key => $value) {
    $result=$value;
    if(!empty($result))
    {
    foreach ($idarray as $key => $value) { 
    if ($value["id"] != $result) {
        $removeid=$key;
        }
    }
   }
}
```

now `$removeid` contains the id to be removed from the databse

Answer (score 0):

```
          $un_array = array();
          foreach ($array as $h) {
              $id = $h['id'];
              array_push($un_array, $id);
          }
          $db_array = array();
          $output   = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM account WHERE account='$username'");
          while ($g = mysql_fetch_assoc($output)) {
              $id = $g['id'];
              array_push($db_array, $id);
          }
          $result = array_diff($db_array, $un_array);
          foreach ($result as $r) {
              mysql_query("DELETE FROM account WHERE id='$r'");
          }
```